# getting location from service but myLocationOverlay doesn't work

Tags: android, service, mylocationoverlay

I have a MapActivity that have to display my current position on the map using myLocationOverlay i get the location from a service.

Here is my Activity:

```
public class ShowMapActivity extends MapActivity {

private MapController mapController;
private MapView mapView;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private MyOverlayUtility itemizedoverlay;
private MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay;
private double latitude;
private double longitude;

public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_showmap);
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
    serviceIntent.setAction("startListening");
    startService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
    // check if the GPS is on
    // isGPSEnable();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(UPDATE_MAP);
    registerReceiver(updateReceiver, filter);

    // Configure the Map
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setSatellite(true);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(14);

    myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mapView.getController().animateTo(
                    myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return true;
}

private final String UPDATE_MAP = "com.livetrekker.activities.UPDTAE_LOCATION";
private BroadcastReceiver updateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        longitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("long", 0);
        latitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("lat", 0);
        Log.e("LOCATION", "lat = " + latitude + " long = " + longitude);
    }
};}
```

And here is my service :

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final String UPDATE_MAP = "com.livetrekker.activities.UPDTAE_LOCATION";
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;

private Location location;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags,
        final int startId) {

    Log.e("Service", "start location");
    // if (intent.getAction().equals("startListening")) {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null) {
        Log.e("LOCATION", "Provider " + provider + " has been selected");
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
            0, this);

    // }
    /*
     * else { if (intent.getAction().equals("stopListening")) {
     * locationManager.removeUpdates(this); locationManager = null; } }
     */

    return START_STICKY;

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
    this.location = location;
    double lng = location.getLongitude();
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    Log.e("SERVICELOCATION", "lat : " + lat + " lng : " + lng);
    Intent updateIntent = new Intent();
    updateIntent.putExtra("long", lng);
    updateIntent.putExtra("lat", lat);
    updateIntent.setAction(UPDATE_MAP);
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(updateIntent);
}

public void onProviderDisabled(final String provider) {
}

public void onProviderEnabled(final String provider) {
}

public void onStatusChanged(final String arg0, final int arg1,
        final Bundle arg2) {
}}
```

So the Location manager works fine i am able to get my latitude and longitude in my activity but the myLocationOverlay doesn't show up.

So is it possible to use that way to display my current position on the map ?

Thanks

EDIT:

I fixe my problem replacing

```
myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mapView.getController().animateTo(
                    myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
        }
    });
```

by :

```
 List overlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    overlays.add(myLocationOverlay);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this code:

```
public class GoogleMapsActivity extends MapActivity {
    public static final String TAG = "GoogleMapsActivity";
    private MapView mapView;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    Geocoder geocoder;
    Location location;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    CountDownTimer locationtimer;
    MapController mapController;
    MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.googlemap);
        initComponents();
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setSatellite(true);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(16);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager == null) {
            Toast.makeText(GoogleMapsActivity.this,
                    "Location Manager Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return;
        }
        location = locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location == null)
            location = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {
            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(GoogleMapsActivity.this,
                    "Location Are" + lat + ":" + lng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
            mapController.animateTo(point, new Message());
            mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);
            List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            listOfOverlays.clear();
            listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
        }
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
                location = l;
                locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
                if (l.getLatitude() == 0 || l.getLongitude() == 0) {
                } else {
                    double lat = l.getLatitude();
                    double lng = l.getLongitude();
                    Toast.makeText(GoogleMapsActivity.this,
                            "Location Are" + lat + ":" + lng,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10f, locationListener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 10f, locationListener);
        locationtimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 5000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if (location != null)
                    locationtimer.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                if (location == null) {
                }
            }
        };
        locationtimer.start();
    }

    public MapView getMapView() {
        return this.mapView;
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.googleMapview);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    class MapOverlay extends Overlay {
        private GeoPoint pointToDraw;

        public void setPointToDraw(GeoPoint point) {
            pointToDraw = point;
        }

        public GeoPoint getPointToDraw() {
            return pointToDraw;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,
                long when) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

            Point screenPts = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, screenPts);

            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.pingreen);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 24, null);
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

(Or) Follow this link: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/android-google-maps-tutorial.html

Comment: The thing is i have to use a service i need my location on other background process ans i don't want to duplicate location code (except if i really have to).